# html page contact form security

Tags: html, security, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have recently designined a website with static information using html bootstrap. Now I want to design my last page Contact Page with the contact info of the person (which has email id) and a contact form.

1. What is the best way to display the email id. I heard many of them use [at] instead of @. Can we write abc[at]xyz.com in mailto? Mailto will open the outlook with the mailid. But how to do that when it is [at].
2. How to build a secure contact form. best way to read data entered by user.
3. I would also like to know ur suggestions on using cms or framework for my static html pages.
4. what should we declare in the Imprints, privacy policy regarding data protection while using contactforms.

Answer (score 0):

Using `[at]` instead of `@` is just for preventing bots and harvesters to gain your email from source or page.

It is ( was ) a good idea to use `[at]` before but today I think it's easy for spammers to gain your email from source with or without using `[at]`

And,  [at] won't work in `mailto` link